# Send media keys to VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, keyboard, itunes

I am running Linux Mint.

I am an Apple Music subscriber, so I had to find a way to install iTunes. I opted to install Windows 7 in a VM. (Windows 10 had issues with VirtualBox's seamless mode).

The one issue I have is that my media keys don't have any effect on the program running in VirtualBox. In order to pause the music, I need to focus the window and press the space bar or the on screen pause button, which is rather inconvenient.

How can I automatically forward my media keys to VirtualBox?

My keyboard is an Alienware TactX.

Answer (score 0):

Mint's XFCE has application shortcuts that you can assign to apparently any key (or combination) in the Keyboard settings.

If you can assign a shortcut to your media keys, then you could run a command or script that would switch to VirtualBox & send the desired keys. Maybe a macro program?

I tried it with my keyboard, it's got 3 "user" keys, an internet key, and volume keys. The "user" keys give an "Unknown key released" error to dmesg / `/var/log/syslog` that says `setkeycodes` should get it working. The internet & volume keys are set ok. But, the audio controls in XFCE intercept the volume keys before passing them to the keyboard shortcut, more config changes would probably fix that.

---

And tried these ideas?

- From https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4263 : "Disabling [or enabling] automatic keyboard capture in the global machine settings"
- Use "Seamless Mode" and move the media player window around like a "regular" linux window? (Needs VirtualBox’s Guest Additions package inside the virtual machine)

[image: Seamless mode]